# Is $PGL_2(q)$ isomorphic to $SL_2(q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $F_q$ denote the field of order $q$.

Define:

- $GL_2(q)$ to be the group of invertible $2$ by $2$ matrices over $F_q$.
- $SL_2(q)$ to be its subgroup consisiting of invertible $2$ by $2$ matrices with determinant $1$.
- $PGL_2(q)=GL_2(q)/D_1$ where $D_1=\{\pmatrix{a& 0\\0& a}:a\in   
     F_q^{\times}\}$.
- $D_2=\{\pmatrix{a& 0\\0& a}:a=\pm1\}$.

It can be shown that $|SL_2(q)|=|PGL_2(q)|=n$ for $n=q(q^2-1)$.

Now I wish to see whether $PGL_2(q)$ is isomorphic to $SL_2(q)$. For $q=2$ it is easy to see that this is true. How do I prove (or disprove) it for $q>2$. I want to use the first isomorphism theorem but I cannot think of any surjective homomorphism between $GL_2(q)$ and $SL_2(q)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are natural maps $\mathrm{SL}_2(q) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{GL}_2(q) \twoheadrightarrow \mathrm{PGL}_2(q)$; composing these gives a map from $\mathrm{SL}_2(q)$ to $\mathrm{PGL}_2(q)$. For $q$ not a power of $2$ this map definitely has a kernel, the subgroup of order $2$ generated by the diagonal matrix $-1$. For $q$ a power of $2$ the kernel is trivial, since in that case $a^2=1$ implies $a=1$ for $a \in F$ a field of char. $2$, so your calculation of the orders shows that over a field of char. $2$ (for $q$ any power of $2$) the groups are isomorphic.

In general, the center of $\mathrm{SL}_2(q)$ consists of scalar matrices $a$ for which $a^2=1$; meanwhile, the group $\mathrm{PGL}_2(q)$ has trivial center: if $g$ commutes with every matrix module scalars, $g h g^{-1}=a$, then $g$ in particular normalizes the torus and hence is either diagonal or anti-diagonal, but a quick calculation shows that $g$ cannot be anti-diagonal and then another that it must itself be scalar.

Added: Andreas just beat me to this, with a much pithier answer.

Answer (score 6):

$\operatorname{PGL}_{2}(q)$ is centreless, while $\operatorname{SL}_{2}(q)$ has a centre $D_{2}$ of order $2$ for $q$ odd.

As a reference, see the [Wikipedia article about the projective special linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group#Finite_fields), or Steve's post ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I can answer the question like this:

Looking at the Fratini subgroups using GAP shows that the Fratini subgroup of $SL_2(3)$ is of order $2$, where the one of $PGL_2(3)$ is trivial.

Assuming the algorithms are correct (which I guess, since they have been testet much), the groups are not isomorphic. You might want to prove this by hand.

So you get a counterexample for your claim.

Comment: In fact, $SL_2(q)$ is the kernel of the determinant og $GL_2(q)$, so you might not get a section for this morphism for every $q$. But it would be interesting if there really is one.