# The projective linear group $PGL_2(q)$ and $SL_2(q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am trying to show that for $q$ odd prime number, the groups $SL_2(q)$ and $PGL_2(q)$ are not isomorphic. On a similar post:[Is $PGL_2(q)$ isomorphic to $SL_2(q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347314/is-pgl-2q-isomorphic-to-sl-2q) . Stephan and Andres stated that studying the center is a way to show that they are not isomorphic. The center of $SL_2(q)$ is clear to me. But how to show that $PGL_2(q)$ is centerless?

Any other approach is welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition about using the orders of elements is a great approach, and your argument regarding the eigenvalues is on the right track. Let's tidy it up a bit:

Given
[ A =
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & a 
\end{pmatrix}
]
in ( PGL_2(q) ), where ( a ) is a generator of ( F_q^\times ), the order of ( A ) is ( q-1 ).

For an element ( B ) in ( SL_2(q) ) with order ( q-1 ), we have ( B^{q-1} = I ). Given that the determinant of ( B ) is 1, the eigenvalues of ( B ) are either ( \pm 1 ).

However, the polynomial ( x^{q-1} - 1 ) has ( q-1 ) distinct roots in ( F_q ) since ( F_q ) is a field. Thus, no ( 2 \times 2 ) matrix in ( SL_2(q) ) can satisfy the equation ( B^{q-1} = I ) without having distinct eigenvalues. This is a contradiction, as our hypothetical matrix would need to have both eigenvalues as 1 or both as -1.

Regarding the centers:

The center of ( SL_2(q) ) consists of scalar matrices with entries in ( F_q^\times ).
[ PGL_2(q) ] is the quotient of ( SL_2(q) ) by its center, so it "collapses" this center to the identity element, making it centerless.

This approach, combined with your element order observation, provides a solid argument that ( SL_2(q) ) and ( PGL_2(q) ) are not isomorphic. Well done!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @Arham Mehta, You mean $PGL_2(q)$ is quotient of $GL_2(q)/Z(q)$ where $Z$ the scalar matrices not the quotient of $SL_2(q)$ right?

Comment: In fact my solution is wrong because am assuming the only solution for $a^2=1$ in $F_q^\times$ is only $\pm 1$ which is false in general.